# Is it Tzaar Baalei Chayyim to feed a live animal to another animal?

Tags: halacha, animals, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

There are many pets available today that experts recommended feeding (infrequently or at times solely) on live animals. Many reptiles (snakes, chameleons, geckos, monitors, etc.) and many fish are recommended to be fed live animals.

In the UK it is illegal to feed live mice/rats/rabbits/chickens to animals such as snakes but allow the feeding of live insects in any event. In countries where this law doesn't apply would it be muttar to feed a mouse to a snake or a cricket to a gecko regularly?

These animals would be considered sheratzim which may make this a null question in any case! What about non-sheratzim, like feeding live fish to a bear at a zoo?

Comment: Snakes don't actually need live animals, they need warm animals. So people warm the dead and frozen mouse in the microwave. (No, I've never owned, or fed, a snake.)

Comment: Some herpatologists recommend live feed for snakes (at least) as supplement feeding to get certain vitamins that they otherwise wouldn't get. In any case, there shouldn't be a difference between a mouse and a cricket.

Comment: We let snakes eat live mice all the time in the wild.

Comment: @DoubleAA "we" dont facilitate snakes eating live mice in the wild. The question is clearly about whether we can deliberately do it.

Comment: Why do you think that feeding live animals is different from any other ways of killing them? E.g. sacrificing, slaughtering, killing for fur, hunting etc?